# Extension of a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, group-actions, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and suppose that there exists an infinite cyclic normal subgroup $H$ of finite index. Let $K$ be it's centralizer. We know that $H$ acts on $\mathbf{R}$ (the real line) via translation, so that a generator $h$ acts via translation by $1$. I want to extend this uniquely to an action of $K$ as follows: if $k\in K$, pick the least $n$ such that $k^n=h^m$ for some $m$, and then $k$ acts as translation by $m/n$ (such $n$ exists because $H$ has finite index). The problem I have is that I can't see why the previous extension indeed defines an action of $K$ on $\mathbf{R}$. Explicitly, I can't see why $$(k_1 k_2)x=k_1(k_2 x)$$ for $k_1,k_2\in K$ and $x\in\mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a simple algebraic method, using that $H$ is a finite index, central cyclic subgroup of $K$. Nonetheless, your question may be answered very quickly, and with a stronger conclusion, using a geometric method, namely Stallings Ends Theorem.

First, the following are easily seen to be equivalent:

1. $G$ contains a normal infinite cyclic subgroup of finite index.
2. $G$ contains an infinite cyclic subgroup of finite index.

Each of these easily implies the following:

3. $G$ is a [2-ended group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallings_theorem_about_ends_of_groups).

This implies, by an easy application of a deep theorem, namely [Stallings Ends Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallings_theorem_about_ends_of_groups), the following:

4. There is a homomorphism $G \to \mathbb{Z}$ or $G \to D_\infty$ (the infinite dihedral group) with finite kernel.

So, all you have to do now is to let the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}$ or $D_\infty$ act on the real line, and it is easy to arrange that this is consistent with the action of your given infinite cyclic normal subgroup $H$. Thus, the entire action of $H$ extends to an action of $G$.

Comment: Prof. Mosher I really appreciate your answer, but it seems a little too much for me to use Stalling's Ends Theorem. I think that I have a proof: as you said, $H$ is a finite index (say $n$), central cyclic subgroup of $K$. Since $H$ is central in $K$, then is normal in $K$. By centrality of $H$ we have that the transfer map $G\rightarrow H$ is given by $g\mapsto g^{n}$. So, for $k_1,k_2\in K$ if $n_1,n_2,n'$ are the least postive integers such that $k_i^{n_i}=h^{m_i}$ and $(k_1k_2)^{n'}=h^{m'}$, then $n_i,n'$ divides $n$. Suppose $n_1l_1=n_2l_2=n'l'=n$.

Comment: All this implies that $h^{m'l'}=h^{m_1l_1+m_2l_2}$, so $m'l'=m_1l_1+m_2l_2$. Finally, if I did it right, we have that $$m'/n'=m_1/n_1+m_2/n_2.$$ So, for every $x\in\mathbf{R}$ we have that $$(k_1k_2)x=k_1(k_2x).$$

Comment: Of course I have a misprint in my first commentary, the transfer map I'm considering goes from $K$ (not $G$) to $H$ so is given by $k\mapsto k^n$.